# How might I increase the network access speed of my iOS and Android app?

Tags: android, ios, performance, parse-platform

Languages Switt and Kotlin.
Platforms iOS and Android.
iOS version 12 and up.
Android version 26 and up.
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.71'
Swift 5
Android   minSdkVersion 26   targetSdkVersion 29

I'm writing an app on both iOS and Android. It's just about finished, but I'm finding that the network access speed is a bit slower than it could be for lists of objects.

When I go to pull up lists (which have images) it can take a few seconds, up to 10, to come up. Other apps like FB seem much more responsive.

I wonder if I can parallelize the Dto fetches, giving each one worker thread beyond the worker thread they are already running on. (None of this blocks the UI as is).

Would parallel fetches, one per worker thread, make a difference?
Would decoding the jpegs in separate threads make a difference?
What is the thread limit (if any) on each platform?
If I spin up 20 worker threads, will some just wait for a core?  This is both Android and iOS.
What other approaches might I use to increase speed.

I am using Parse.
https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX
https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android

What other tricks to experienced app developers use to get their Kotlin and Swift network based apps to run faster?

I'm mainly a server side dev, so I think I'm pretty good about making queries and the like efficient, but we shall see.  :)

Thanks in advance.
-Chris

Answer (score 0):

Before fix the problem you need to make some tests:

1. your network tests via [www.speedtest.net](http://www.speedtest.net) (about 3-5 tests)
2. your data provider test using a third-party tools such [Postman](https://www.postman.com)
3. launch the [profiler tool in AndroidStudio](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/network-profiler)

After that you will find out the root of your problem (slow connection speed, slow your data server or performance issues in your app code).